# С# Нужно сохранять файл пока не сохранит

Tags: c#, обработка-ошибок, обработка

Есть автоматика на excel на C#, через раз при сохранении выдает ошибку
Ошибка

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Document not s
aved.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook.SaveAs(Object Filename, Object Fi
leFormat, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object ReadOnlyRecommended,
Object CreateBackup, XlSaveAsAccessMode AccessMode, Object ConflictResolution, O
bject AddToMru, Object TextCodepage, Object TextVisualLayout, Object Local)
```

Как сохраняю

```
Workbook.SaveAs(Savefile, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
Workbook.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
oWord.Workbooks.Close();
oWord.Quit();
```

Нужно сделать, если выдает ошибку то повторить сохранение до тех пор пока не сохранить
Почитал что можно сделать через обработку ошибок либо через проверку файла но как я не знаю

Comment: Почитайте про try-catch

Comment: Что-то не очень хорошая идея. Ну допустим юзер указал путь, к которому запрещён доступ. То есть тогда ваша программа будет пытаться сохранить вечно?

Comment: Ну я думаю можно указать ко-во раз попыток сохранения

Comment: "Interop.Excel" обычно не самая хорошая идея

Answer (score 0):

Повторять сохранение или нет можно спросить у пользователя программы.

```
private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool isNotSaved = SaveToFile();

    if (isNotSaved)
    {
        while (AskRepeatSaving())
        {
            if (!SaveToFile()) break; 
        }
    }
}

private bool SaveToFile()
{
    try
    {
        //здесь логика сохранения в файл
        //...

        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"<--Ошибка сохранения в файл: {ex.Message}");
        return true;
    }
}

private bool AskRepeatSaving()
{
    string message = "Возникла ошибка сохранения файла.\nПовторить попытку сохранения?";
    string caption = "Ошибка сохранения файла";

    var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question, MessageBoxResult.Yes);

    return result == MessageBoxResult.Yes;
}
```